# Making a common DB for one app across multiple django projects

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have 3 distinct Django projects (or instances) running on the same Ubuntu server (for the same user) in different folders. Lets call these instances (D1, D2, D3). All the 3 projects use sqlite3 as DB.

All the 3 projects aside from their inherent differences also have a single common django Model called "Word" (that is basically responsible for storing word images). there can be millions of entries for word model for each of the django projects at any given time.

The problem I am encountering is that I need to frequently transfer the word instances from one project to another. the Volume of the words to be transferred is huge (millions of word model instances per day).

My current solution is very inefficient, what I am doing is to export all the word entries from D1 project to a single folder and import all the entries from the folder to D2 project.

Is there any way to make a common database that all the 3 projects can access for the "Word" model? this will make life much easier where to transfer the words from D1 to D2, I would just have to change a field (probably belongs_to) in all the concerned words from "D1" to "D2".

Any help on how to implement this solution or some other idea to solve this issue will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: Just point all the projects at the same absolute path location of the DB?

Comment: Simply switch to postgresql or any other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two (or more) databases in your project:

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    },
    'common': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'name': '/path/to/common/db',
    },
}
```

you can do this in all the Django applications, where you thus refer to a common database, preferably the database of one of the Django apps by the two others.

Now the problem is how we can let Django know we want to "talk" to that database. We do that with the [**`.using(…)`** directive <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#using). So we can work with:

```
words = Word.objects.using('common')
```

this will let Django use the `common` database instead of the `default` one.

This might be a bit tiresome, since we will need to use that each time. A solution is to work with a custom manager for `objects`:

```
class WordManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).using('common')


class Word(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = WordManager()
```

so now when we use `Word.objects.all()` it will be routed to the `/path/to/common/db.sqlite` database instead.

That being said, using different databases has some disadvantage, the most notorious one that we can not make JOINs on tables in different databases. So it is not a "*silver bullet*" solution.